# React Redux how to write action logic for show and hide my category

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

How to write  action logic for show and hide  element. Right now my all category and subcategory  showing but I want to show theme after user click. See the screenshot below. Assume user click on electronic category so it should be open only electronic category. If user click on another category then previous main category should be hide.  here is my code:. Right now I am fetching api for show my all category.

```
export const adsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ads_category",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // setProducts(state, action) {
    //     state.data = action.payload;
    // },
    // setStatus(state, action) {
    //     state.status = action.payload;
    // },
},
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
        .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.data = action.payload;
            state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.ERROR;
        });
},
})
```

**my  page.js**

```
const PostAds = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const display_category = useSelector(state=>state.ads)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  
}, []);

 

  
    return (
      <>.....</>)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create initial state

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  electronic: false,
  pet: false,
  car: false,
};
```

Then write actions. redux toolkit already creates actions but I will be explicit for people who do not use rtk.

```
export const displayElectronicComponent = () => ({
  type: categoryComponentActionsTypes.DISPLAY_ELECTRONIC,
});

export const displayPetComponent = () => ({
  type: categoryComponentActionsTypes.DISPLAY_PET,
});

export const displayCarComponent = () => ({
  type: categoryComponentActionsTypes.DISPLAY_CAR,
});
```

then

```
 reducers: {
    setElectronic(state, action) {
         state.electronic = !state.electronic;
         state.pet=false;
         state.car=false
     },
     setPet(state, action) {
         state.pet = !state.pet;
         state.electronic=false
         state.car=false;
     },
     setCar(state,action){
         state.car=!state.car
         state.electronic=false
         state.car=false
     }
},


export const {setElectronic,setPet,setCar}=adsSlice.actions
```

then on each box, let's say for electronics.

```
  <ElectronicComponent onClick={dispatch(setElectronic)} />
```

Now you conditionally render components

```
 // named reducer as "ads"
  const { electronic, pet,car } = useSelector((state) => state.ads);
```

whichever is `true` show its subcategories

Comment: Thnaks for your solution.  You might be little bit misunderstood. My all Main category should be display default. If user click on any main category then it's related subcategory will be  show and I have too many category so it will be not good practice put my all category name in INITIAL_STATE.  Assume I have 1000 or 2000 category so it will be not good put all  category name in INITIAL_STATE.

Comment: That's the logic part you will have to think of yourself, can't write the exact code. Once you know store, think how you can use it.